# not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

I am a noob in python, I want to have e0,e1,...,e10 have the values of c0, c1,..., c10.I,tried doing that and there is the code.The problem is it didn't work. it says **"TypeError: not enough arguments for format string".** counts and countr are integers. I searched and found that i need to use curly braces to fix it but i don't know how. I don't understand how exec works. I just got code from another question.

```
exec("e%s = 'c{}'.format(counts) " %countr)
```

Comment: Why don't you use list or dictionary?

Comment: Use a `list` for all that is holy! `e[0]`, `e[1]` is much more sensible to begin with.

Comment: ok thanks im closing this, if i can

Comment: `e = ['c%s' % i for i in range(11)]`

Comment: Sorry for the bad advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to answer the question you're asking, I'm going to answer the question you should be asking.

You are trying to create variables named e1, e2, etc. Using `exec` is absolutely the wrong tool for that. Instead, use a dictionary and then you don't have to resort to such complicated code.

```
e = {}
for i in range(10):
    e[i] = "c%s" % i
```

With that you now have a dictionary that is easily accessible without having to use `exec`:

```
print("1:", e[1])
```